# MediaPlayer skips first 3 seconds on Android P (API 28)

Tags: android, audio, android-9.0-pie

MediaPlayer usually works just fine playing my files from disk.  However, when I use Android P (API 28), MediaPlayer skips the first 3 seconds of my audio files.

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("filepath.m4a");
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Tested on an emulator using a Nexus 5x
Also tested on a real device using a Pixel 1.

Comment: Media Player can cause meaningless problems so it is not a good option. You can use ExoPlayer which developed by Google

Comment: thanks!  I've converted to use ExoPlayer now, so much better

Comment: Also seeing this issue, sadly migrating to Exoplayer is not a realistic option for me - if anyone finds a solution to this please do say